# Kivy Infinite Looping ScrollView

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, scrollview

I am trying to create a `ScrollView` in Kivy with widgets that loop infinitely like in this demo I found online:

[image: Demo]

I have tried to remove widgets outside the ScrollView's bounds and add them back to the top or bottom, depending on their original location. However, this made the whole app flicker and glitch and ultimately did not work. If anyone has a method of achieving this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I need exactly this :( Have you ever been able to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found anything yet. I'm trying to make one myself but that's more of a side project right now

Comment: Sad. I started working on my own as well. Do you want me to post it here if I finish it?

Comment: Yes please! I'll do the same if/when I finish

Comment: I've got a very rough - but working - version ready. If you want/need inspiration or feedback/potential issues let me know  :  (Its badly optimized (rather not optimized at all)) However i post the final version here anyways - as soon as its done.
https://github.com/CoreTaxxe/Kivy-LoopScrollView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a custom class based on kivy's `Stencilview` and `RelativeLayout`.
It's used pretty much like `kivy.uix.recycleview` and supports looping. It's somewhat unoptimized but works pretty well. No x-axis scrolling (yet). Should be capable of processing an infinite amount of data without any performance loss. (Tested with 10.000.000 data entries => no lag)).
please don't quote me on anything inside `on_touch_down`, `on_touch_move`, `on_touch_up`, or any function called inside it (the only exception is `scroll_y`) cause I have no idea how they work.

```py
from functools import partial

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.compat import iteritems
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import sp
from kivy.properties import DictProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.stencilview import StencilView
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class LoopEntry(Widget):
    data_index = NumericProperty(0)
    data = DictProperty(None, allow_none=True)
    hidden = BooleanProperty(False)

    def is_hidden(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        return self.hidden

    def hide(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        self.opacity = 0
        self.hidden = True

    def show(self):
        """

        :return:
        """
        self.opacity = 1
        self.hidden = False

    def update(self, data):
        """
        overwrite this function if values other than attributes are needed
        :param data:
        :return:
        """
        assert isinstance(data, dict)

        # assign data
        self.data = data

        # apply values
        for key, value in iteritems(data):
            setattr(self, key, value)


class LoopContainer(RelativeLayout, StencilView):
    pass


class LoopContainerDebug(RelativeLayout):
    pass


class LoopScrollView(RelativeLayout):
    """
    Main data source. Contains the data that needs to be exchanged.
    Data can be manipulated without a whole redraw. Might cause unwanted behaviour
    like blank lines and incorrect orders if not properly updated.
    Setting this value causes a complete refresh.
    """
    data = ListProperty()

    """
    Children height. All children need to be the same height else 
    unwanted behaviour might occur. 
    Altering this value causes a complete refresh.
    """
    children_height = NumericProperty(44)

    """
    Amount of widgets added to the minimum widgets. (Very) Big numbers may cause lag.
    Altering this value causes a complete refresh
    """
    protection_amount = NumericProperty(4)

    """
    viewclass is used to set the class type the widgets should be 
    future version might support manual adding of widgets
    Altering this value causes a complete refresh.
    """
    viewclass = ObjectProperty(LoopEntry)

    """
    controls looping behaviour.
    """
    loop = BooleanProperty(True)

    """
    debugging option. shows hidden entries. not possible to switch
    while running (yet)
    """
    debug = BooleanProperty(False)

    """
    scroll timeout. If the mouse has not been moved 'scroll_distance' within this time, dispatch the touch to children
    in milliseconds
    """
    scroll_timeout = NumericProperty(200)

    """
    touch distance. Distance mouse needs to be moved
    in pixel
    """
    scroll_distance = NumericProperty('20dp')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """

        :param kwargs:
        """

        # minimum widgets controls min/max amount of widgets on screen. Readonly.
        self.__minimum_widgets = 0

        # controls overscroll blocking if loop is disabled
        self.__overscroll_block_y = "free"

        # container
        _kwargs = {
            "size_hint": (None, None),
            "size": (0, 0)
        }
        self.container = LoopContainer(**_kwargs) if not kwargs.get('debug', False) else LoopContainerDebug(**_kwargs)

        # init super values
        super(LoopScrollView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # add container
        self.add_widget(self.container)

        # create widgets
        self.__create_widgets()

        # no idea
        self._drag_touch = None

    def on_pos(self, widget, value) -> None:
        """

        :param widget:
        :param value:
        :return:
        """

    def on_size(self, widget, value) -> None:
        """

        :param widget:
        :param value:
        :return:
        """
        # set container size
        self.container.size = self.size

        # recreate widgets
        self.__create_widgets()

    def on_data(self, widget, value) -> None:
        """
        called if new data is set. Forces complete refresh. Use with care.
        :param widget: widget event belongs to
        :param value: event value
        :return: None
        """
        self.__create_widgets()

    def on_protection_amount(self, widget, value) -> None:
        """
        Forces complete refresh. Use with care.
        :param widget: widget event belongs to
        :param value: event value
        :return: None
        """
        self.__create_widgets()

    def on_viewclass(self, widget, value) -> None:
        """
        sets the viewclass used to entries
        Forces complete refresh
        :param widget: widget
        :param value: value
        :return: None
        """
        self.__create_widgets()

    def on_children_height(self, widget, value) -> None:
        """
        Changes the children height.
        Forces complete refresh.
        :param widget: widget
        :param value: value
        :return: None
        """
        self.__create_widgets()

    def __create_widgets(self) -> None:
        """
        clear all widgets and recreate
        :return: None
        """
        # remove all widgets
        self.container.clear_widgets()

        # calculate the minimum amount of required widgets
        self.minimum_widgets = round(self.height / self.children_height) + self.protection_amount

        # adding entries to the stencil view in reversed order to start with the smallest value (index 0) at top
        for entry in range(self.minimum_widgets, 0, -1):
            # create widget instance
            _tmp_entry = self.viewclass(
                size_hint=(1, None),
                height=self.children_height,
                pos=(0, self.height - self.children_height * entry)
            )

            # add to container
            self.container.add_widget(_tmp_entry)

        # refresh all widgets from given index and apply data values
        self.__refresh_from_index(0)

    def __refresh_from_index(self, index=0) -> None:
        """
        refreshes widgets from given index
        :param index: index to start with (very top entry)
        :return: None
        """
        # return if data is empty
        if not self.data:
            return

        # reset widget positions to prevent weird behaviour
        self.__reset_widget_positions(brute=True)

        # reduce overhead. Slightly.
        _data_length = len(self.data)
        # loop through children and set values from given index
        for child in self.container.children:
            # if the current index exceeds the lengths and looping is disabled hide the widget
            if index >= _data_length and not self.loop:
                # Note : I dislike direct changing of values -_-
                if not child.is_hidden():
                    child.hide()  # hide child
                child.data_index = index
            else:
                _normalized_index = index % _data_length
                # get the new data value for the widget
                _data_value = self.data[_normalized_index]
                child.update(_data_value)
                child.data_index = _normalized_index

                if child.is_hidden():
                    child.show()

            # increase index
            index += 1

    def __reset_widget_positions(self, brute=False) -> None:
        """
        resets widget positions. Does not take into account values or
        value positions.
        If brute is True positions will be reset forcefully meaning data may mix up.
        If brute is False positions will be scrolled meaning values will remain ordered.
        :param brute: boolean
        :return: None
        """
        if brute:
            # forcefully reset children
            for child in self.container.children:
                child.y = self.height - (child.height * (self.get_child_index(child) + 1))
        else:
            # get top child
            _top_child = self.container.children[0]
            # loop until child's y value matches the top threshold
            while _top_child.y != self.height - _top_child.height:
                # scroll by up to ensure proper order
                self.scroll_y(1)

    def __trigger_overscroll(self, entry: (LoopEntry, None), state):
        """

        :param entry:
        :param state:
        :return:
        """
        # trigger overscroll for down
        if state == "bottom" and entry is not None:

            # reset child to a proper spot
            while entry.y != 0:
                # scroll in the fastest direction
                self.scroll_y(1 if entry.y < 0 else -1)

            # set overscroll AFTER scrolling
            self.__overscroll_block_y = "bottom"

        # for up
        elif state == "top" and entry is not None:

            # reset child to proper spot
            while entry.y != self.height - entry.height:
                self.scroll_y(1 if entry.y < self.height - entry.height else 1)

            # set overscroll AFTER scrolling
            self.__overscroll_block_y = "top"

        # reset else
        else:
            # free scrolling
            self.__overscroll_block_y = "free"

    def __update_entry(self, entry: LoopEntry, direction) -> None:
        """

        :param entry:
        :param direction:
        :return:
        """

        # get data length
        _data_length = len(self.data)

        # check direction
        if direction == "down":
            # get new index
            _data_index = entry.data_index + self.minimum_widgets

            if self.loop:
                # normalize data index
                _normalized_data_index = _data_index % _data_length
                # update entry
                entry.update(self.data[_normalized_data_index])
                # set data index
                entry.data_index = _normalized_data_index
                # show entry
                if entry.is_hidden():
                    entry.show()
            else:
                # if loop is disabled and data index exceeds either direction
                if _data_index >= _data_length or _data_index < 0:
                    # hide children
                    if not entry.is_hidden():
                        entry.hide()
                else:
                    # update entry from data index
                    entry.update(self.data[_data_index])

                    # show entry
                    if entry.is_hidden():
                        entry.show()

                # set data index
                entry.data_index = _data_index

        elif direction == "up":
            # get new data index
            _data_index = entry.data_index - self.minimum_widgets

            # if looping is enabled
            if self.loop:
                # normalize index
                _normalized_data_index = _data_index % _data_length
                # update entry
                entry.update(self.data[_normalized_data_index])
                # set data index
                entry.data_index = _normalized_data_index
                # show entry
                if entry.is_hidden():
                    entry.show()
            else:
                if _data_index < 0 or _data_index >= _data_length:
                    # hide children
                    if not entry.is_hidden():
                        entry.hide()
                else:
                    # update entry from data index
                    entry.update(self.data[_data_index])

                    # show entry
                    if entry.is_hidden():
                        entry.show()

                    # set data index
                entry.data_index = _data_index

        else:
            # error
            raise Exception

    def get_child_index(self, child) -> (int, None):
        """
        returns the index if the child exists in list else None
        :param child: child instance
        :return: int,None
        """
        return self.container.children.index(child) if child in self.container.children else None

    def scroll_y(self, delta_y) -> None:
        """
        scroll by given amount
        :param delta_y: delta value in pixels
        :return: None
        """
        # set highest and lowest children (needed for rotation)
        _highest, _lowest = self.container.children[0], self.container.children[0]

        # round delta y
        delta_y = round(delta_y)
        # get data length
        data_length = len(self.data)

        # control var
        _free_block = True

        # loop through children
        for child in self.container.children:
            # increase/decrease children y position
            child.y += delta_y
            # update highest and lowest children
            _highest = child if child.y > _highest.y else _highest
            _lowest = child if child.y < _lowest.y else _lowest

            # check for loop condition
            if not self.loop:
                # if current child's index exceeds or evens data length and is higher than given
                # threshold trigger overscroll event for bottom
                if child.data_index >= data_length - 1 and child.y >= 0:
                    self.__trigger_overscroll(child, 'bottom')
                    _free_block = False

                # if current child's index is smaller or evens 0 and is higher than the given
                # threshold trigger overscroll event for top
                elif child.data_index <= 0 and child.y <= self.height - child.height:
                    self.__trigger_overscroll(child, 'top')
                    _free_block = False

        # unblock if block is free to be unblocked
        if _free_block:
            self.__trigger_overscroll(None, 'reset')

        # check if swap is needed
        if _highest.y > self.height + _highest.height and delta_y > 0:
            # set new y for highest if it exceeds max height
            _highest.y = _lowest.y - _highest.height
            self.__update_entry(_highest, direction="down")

        elif _lowest.y < 0 - _lowest.height - _lowest.height and delta_y < 0:
            _lowest.y = _highest.y + _highest.height
            self.__update_entry(_lowest, direction="up")

    def _get_uid(self, prefix='sv'):
        return '{0}.{1}'.format(prefix, self.uid)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        x, y = touch.pos

        if not self.collide_point(x, y):
            touch.ud[self._get_uid('svavoid')] = True
            return super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)

        if self._drag_touch or ('button' in touch.profile and touch.button.startswith('scroll')):
            return super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)

        # no mouse scrolling, so the user is going to drag with this touch.
        self._drag_touch = touch
        uid = self._get_uid()
        touch.grab(self)
        touch.ud[uid] = {
            'mode': 'unknown',
            'dx': 0,
            'dy': 0
        }
        Clock.schedule_once(self._change_touch_mode, self.scroll_timeout / 1000.)
        return True

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self._get_uid('svavoid') in touch.ud or self._drag_touch is not touch:
            return super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_move(touch) or self._get_uid() in touch.ud

        if touch.grab_current is not self:
            return True

        uid = self._get_uid()
        ud = touch.ud[uid]
        mode = ud['mode']

        if mode == 'unknown':
            ud['dx'] += abs(touch.dx)
            ud['dy'] += abs(touch.dy)

            if ud['dx'] > sp(self.scroll_distance):
                mode = 'drag'
            if ud['dy'] > sp(self.scroll_distance):
                mode = 'drag'

            ud['mode'] = mode

        if mode == 'drag':
            if (touch.dy > 0 and self.__overscroll_block_y == "bottom" or
                    touch.dy < 0 and self.__overscroll_block_y == "top"):
                pass
            else:
                self.scroll_y(touch.dy)

        return True

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if self._get_uid('svavoid') in touch.ud:
            return super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_up(touch)

        if self._drag_touch and self in [x() for x in touch.grab_list]:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            self._drag_touch = None
            ud = touch.ud[self._get_uid()]

            if ud['mode'] == 'unknown':
                super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
                Clock.schedule_once(partial(self._do_touch_up, touch), .1)
        else:
            if self._drag_touch is not touch:
                super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_up(touch)

        return self._get_uid() in touch.ud

    def _do_touch_up(self, touch, *largs):
        super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_up(touch)
        # don't forget about grab event!
        for x in touch.grab_list[:]:
            touch.grab_list.remove(x)
            x = x()
            if not x:
                continue
            touch.grab_current = x
            super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_up(touch)
        touch.grab_current = None

    def _change_touch_mode(self, *largs):
        if not self._drag_touch:
            return

        uid = self._get_uid()
        touch = self._drag_touch
        ud = touch.ud[uid]

        if ud['mode'] != 'unknown':
            return
        touch.ungrab(self)
        self._drag_touch = None
        touch.push()
        touch.apply_transform_2d(self.parent.to_widget)
        super(LoopScrollView, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        touch.pop()
        return


# ------------------ Showcase ------------------ #

from kivy.uix.button import Button


class LoopLabel(LoopEntry, Label):
    pass


class LoopButton(LoopEntry, Button):
    pass


__style = ("""
<LoopLabel>:
    color : 1,1,1
    text: "test"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb : 1,1,1
        Line:
            rectangle: (*self.pos,self.width ,self.height )
            
<LoopContainer,LoopContainerDebug>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb : 1,0,0
        Line:
            rectangle: (0+1,0+1,self.width - 1,self.height -1 )
            width:5
""")


class InfiniteScrollingScrollView(App):
    def build(self):
        root = RelativeLayout()
        root.bind(on_touch_down=lambda x, y: print("-" * 10))
        sv = LoopScrollView(
            size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), pos_hint={'center': (0.5, 0.5)}, viewclass=LoopLabel, debug=False
        )
        sv.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(1000)]
        root.add_widget(sv)
        return root


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Builder.load_string(__style)
    InfiniteScrollingScrollView().run()
```

Comment: The code takes some time to load the GUI but once it's loaded it seems to work pretty well. Great job!

Comment: Thats just because of this line here : `sv.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(10000000)]`. Python simply needs some time to generate a list with 10 million objects. It should be instantaneous with fewer items. And thanks!  
Edit : Note that it is not fully debugged yet and may have uncaught edge cases. I will hover improve and update it.

Answer (score 0):

i think this helpful but not the Answer
and this will help https://youtu.be/l8Imtec4ReQ in minute 59:30

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

kv=Builder.load_string('''
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x:False
    scroll_type:['bars', 'content']
    bar_width:'20dp'
    GridLayout:
        id:g
        cols:1
        size_hint:(1,None)
        height:self.minimum_height
''')

class a(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(100):self.root.ids.g.add_widget(Label(text=str(i),size_hint=(1, None),size=(1, 20)))
a().run()
```

Comment: This is mainly a tutorial on how to use a `ScrollView` and does not answer my question, but thank you for the answer :)